# Interaction of JSDoc and type mapping

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm looking for a complete list (preferrably from a "reputable source") of information on how TypeScript's JSDoc works with types and their mappings and modifications.

The obvious basics are that `Pick` and `Omit` keep the initial JSDoc:

```
const any: any = {};
type A = {
    /** FOO */ foo: 1,
    /** BAR */ bar: 2
}
let A: A = any;
A.foo
// ^# FOO
let A2: Pick<A, 'foo'> = any;
A2.foo
// ^# FOO
let A3: Omit<A, 'bar'> = any;
A3.foo
// ^# FOO
```

The more advanced case is that mapped types keep JSDoc:

```
type B = { [K in keyof A]: false }
let B: B = any;
B.foo
// ^# FOO
```

Thus, I'm looking for the complete list of techniques which could be used for JSDoc manipulation, and info on how JSDoc in TS works at all to understand those techniques better.

Particulary (but not limited to):

- Is it possible to transform `{ /** foo */ a: 1 }` into `{ /** foo */ b: 1 }` ?
- Is it possible to add JSDoc with a `function addJsdoc<T, ?>(fnWithoutJsdoc: T): <?<T>>` wrapper?

Related: [`(Github)/TypeScript: Feature Request: Documented Utility Type #41165`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41165)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript seems to do its best to preserve annotations when the *exact same* key is used, and drops it in all other cases. So you don't have much control over this.

---

I thought maybe key remapping would do it, but even in the simplest case, the annotations are dropped.

This works:

```
type B = { [K in keyof A]: false }
declare const B: B;
B.foo // # FOO
```

But this does not:

```
type B = { [K in keyof A as `${K}`]: false }
declare const B: B;
B.foo // no annotation
```

Here `K` is being transformed to `${K}`, which for string properties should be the same. But the mere fact that `K` is not used directly breaks the annotations.

---

Typescript just does not have APIs for accessing and managing these types of annotations. It simply picks them up and propagates them through in the simple cases where it can.

Which means, sadly, that the answer to your questions are:

> Is it possible to transform `{ /** foo */ a: 1 }` into { /** foo */ b: 1 }` ?

No.

> Is it possible to add JSDoc with a function `addJsdoc<T, ?>(fnWithoutJsdoc: T): <?<T>>` wrapper?

No.